# Upload JavaEE application to remote tomcat inside a cluster

Tags: java, tomcat, jenkins

Our application is served by tomcat inside a cluster which contains a lot of windows 2008 servers. These servers are behind a Hardware Loader Balancer and Firewall. Usually one of the server can be exposed outside the Loader Balancer for system maintenance.

And we commit our source codes to a git repository, and then the application will be built by Jenkins which have the internet access.

[image]

Now I wonder if it is possible to update the application from Jenkins Server to the cluster?